# Should methods that return boolean be named after a question or an assertion?

Tags: naming, naming-standards, boolean

Many naming conventions recommend that methods returning a boolean (also called *predicate methods*) should be named after **a question**. My question is: don't they really mean the methods should be named after **an assertion**?

The difference may be subtle, but you end up with different names in some cases:

- *question*: is_pixel_transparent(...)
- *assertion*: pixel_is_transparent(...)

Sometimes, this makes no difference and the phrasing is the same:

- *question*: end_of_file(...)
- *assertion*: end_of_file(...)

Besides, it seems like most of the time, what people call "questions" are actually *assertions*.

- key_exists(...) --> this is not a question, this is an assertion. 
  Example usage: if (key_exists(...)) ...
- array_contains_element(...) --> this is not a question, this is an assertion. 
  Example usage:
  if (array_contains_element(...)) ...

So, to restate the question, is everyone meaning *assertion* when they say *question*?

Comment: don't all these things you call assertions become questions when adding a questionmark? Key_Exists?

Comment: 'Jon Skeet is awesome' is an assertion. 'Is Jon Skeet awesome?' is a question. See the difference. See the difference?

Comment: @Pieter, no, not in proper English. The question mark makes a sentence a question?

Comment: @Steven, I think my first example addresses the first half of your comment, and the second example the second half of it. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @rick: an assertion must be true, otherwise the program is in an undefined/error state. A question may or may not be true. I think of it as control-failure vs control-flow.

Comment: @PieterB In some languages (e.g. Ruby), you actually *can* add a question mark to the end of the method name. ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The point of naming conventions is not to make your code read like English, so you might be over-analyzing a bit. In many languages, it is customary to prefix a method or function returning a boolean result or a boolean variable with `is`, when it makes sense. There are other traditions (e.g. Lisp, Ruby), where a suffix `?` is used instead. (An older Lisp tradition is the suffix `-p` for *predicate*).

- In your pixel transparency example, `is_transparent` should be a method of a pixel object. If you are in a language that does not have objects, but want to simulate an OOP style, then the type would usually be the prefix: `Pixel_is_transparent`. Note that the prefix `is` is only used to *highlight* the boolean nature of this method; it is already implied by the method call (`pixel.transparent` works as well, but this can become too ambiguous with other property names).
- To test for EOF, a method could be named `at_eof`. This interprets the *end of file* as a location in the stream, whereas `stream.is_eof` would work as well: here, the EOF is a specific state.
- To tests whether an entry exists, `collection.exists(key)` would be better.
- `array_contains_element` isn't a good method name, as it contains a type, and the unecessary `element`. Better: `array.contains(elem)`.

All of the names I suggest are assertions, or more precisely: predicates. Using questions does not make any linguistic sense when these predicates are used in an *if-then-else* contex. The word “*assertion*” is probably not optimal here, as it is used to describe the testing of invariants in many languages. The word [“*predicate*”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_%28mathematical_logic%29) would be better: a statement that is either true or false. A statement is phrased as if it were true, not as a question. The statement `1 ∈ {}` – “`1` is element of the empty set” or “the empty set contains `1`” is a false statement. The question “does the empty set contain the number 1?” can be answered with *yes* or *no*, but it isn't true or false.

Comment: +1 for the note about how the term "assertion" not being the right term to use here because of possible confusion.